# Azure API Management service - getting the subscription key into Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am currently using Azure API Management service on the consumption plan. While it's great it doesn't built-in analytics.

I have 15 users each with their own subscription key. At the moment I have no visibility on the usage of each user. I would like to get the subscription key for each API call and pass that into Application Insights.

Is this possible using a custom metric?

This query is working great however I'd like to get the subscription key included as well.

thank you so much!

```
requests
| project
    timestamp,
    url,
    operation_Name,    
    success,
    resultCode,
    duration,
    cloud_RoleName
| where timestamp > ago(1d)
| order by timestamp desc
| take 100
```

Comment: Are you using Azure DevOps? If so, please describe in detail how your current problem relates to Azure DevOps. So that we can understand your problem more clearly.

Comment: Actually it is not an issue.. OP is asking for additional log.I think the Devops tag is not relevant.

Comment: Hii think  azure API Management's built-in logging and analytics features do not directly show subscription keys in the telemetry data available in Application Insights, you can get this done by modifying the backend code possibly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add this header in the app insights integration:
[image]

Then you may find it in the app insights logs:

[image]

and use the following query:

```
requests
| project timestamp, url, customDimensions["Request-Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"], operation_Name
| where timestamp > ago(1d)
```